# Flatten 3D array containing objects to 2D removing duplicated objects by it's parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, underscore.js

I have a 3D array with objects inside:

```
[
    [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }],
    [{ id: 3 }],
    [{ id: 3 }, { id: 4 }]
]
```

How to flatten it including removing duplicated `id` parameter?

```
[{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }]
```

I think underscore would be helpful with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Underscore [flatten](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten) and [unique](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) to accomplish this. However, whenever you are using multiple underscore operations, it is a good time to consider using the [underscore chainging](http://underscorejs.org/#chaining) with `chain` and `value`:

```
var data = [
    [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }],
    [{ id: 3 }],
    [{ id: 3 }, { id: 4 }]
];

var result = _.chain(data)
                  .flatten()
                  .uniq(function(o) {
                      return o.id;
                   })
                  .value();

console.log('result', result);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0udLde0s/3/

**Even shorter with current Underscore.js**

If you use a recent version of Underscore.js (I tried current which is 1.8.3 right now), you can use `.uniq('id')` so it makes it even shorter:

```
var result = _.chain(data)
                  .flatten()
                  .uniq('id')
                  .value();
```

Comment: You can replace the function in the call to uniq with the string 'id' e.g. `.uniq('id')`

Comment: @GruffBunny Ah, you're right, in underscorejs current version, `.uniq('id')` works but not in the older version (1.5) I happened to use on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 3):

```
var a = [
    [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }],
    [{ id: 3 }],
    [{ id: 3 }, { id: 4 }]
];

var flattened = _(a).flatten().uniq('id').value();
```

Of course you have to include [lodash](https://lodash.com/) to your webpage.

Comment: It is nice lodash has the short cut for getting a property in `uniq`!

Comment: Underscore does that as well

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`_.flatten`](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten), and [`_.uniq`](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq), like so

```js
var data = [
    [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }],
    [{ id: 3 }],
    [{ id: 3 }, { id: 4 }]
];

var result = _.uniq(_.flatten(data), function (el) {
    return el.id;
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any library for this, it's quite simple:

```js
function flatten(arr)
{
  var map = {};
  var flatArray = [];
  function pushToMap(o) {
    if(map[o.id])
      return;
  
    map[o.id] = true;
    flatArray.push(o);
  }
  function arrRecurse(a) {
    if(a.length === undefined)
      pushToMap(a);
    else {
      a.forEach(function(i) {
        arrRecurse(i);
      });
    }
  }

  arrRecurse(arr);
  return flatArray;
}

var _3dArray = [
    [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }],
    [{ id: 3 }],
    [{ id: 3 }, { id: 4 }]
];

alert(JSON.stringify(flatten(_3dArray)));
```

Comment: Nice non-library solution, but sometimes it's better to use one, especially when it makes your code cleaner and easier to read or maintain. We can't always avoid using 3rd party solutions, that's why almost every page has at least jQuery included.

Comment: And one more thing, when checking for 'undefined' do it like this: `if (typeof a === 'undefined') {...}`. `if (a === undefined)` will throw an exception.

Comment: @itachi - Your right, but no one said anything about a web page. Today, node is a leading platform. Even when considering client side web pages, loading any library has it's costs (async request, loading, parsing...) it depends on complexity needed.

Comment: @itachi - Regarding using `undefined`, you're wrong. `a.length` WON'T throw an exception - `typeof` is unneeded.

Comment: You're right. My brain did not catch NotEnoughCoffee exception.

Answer (score 0):

## No library, only native JS :

```js
var ar = [
  [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }],
  [{ id: 3 }],
  [{ id: 3 }, { id: 4 }]
];

//start
var output = [];
for (var x = 0, al = {}; x < ar.length; x++)
  for (var y = 0, t = ar[x][y]; y < ar[x].length; y++, t = ar[x][y])
      al[t.id] = (!al[t.id]) ? output.push(t) : 1;
//end

document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(output);
```